# Handling events from within a PopupWindow

Tags: java, datepicker, javafx, javafx-8, timepicker

I've made my own TimePicker that is supposed to work very much like DatePicker. I would like to know the best way to handle an event such as selecting a time and confirming it from the PopupWindow.

I could:

- Make my TimePicker's popup node (a separate FXML and controller) define an interface and force the TimePicker parent to implement the methods to handle the selected date. (I'd MUCH like to avoid using interfaces in this manner. It seems like a terribly way to do things.)
- Register some kind of custom EventHandler and listener to the popup window? Then, if I click OKAY after selecting a date from the PopupWindow, an event can be fired all the way up to the TimePicker.
- Implement some kind of callback-like function. In android, for example, there were options for going to another screen solely to retrieve a result. I'm not sure if JavaFX has that kind of thing. The screens are quite separated from each other.

Comment: Why not just expose a property?

Comment: I suppose I could do that. A `BooleanProperty confirmed`, for example. Upon hitting OKAY from the Popup, confirmed is set to true and the listener from the TimePicker will respond. But won't I have to reset the confirmed property back to false? EDIT: Or it would be easier to expose the current `ObjectProperty<LocalTime> value` of the TimePickerClockPopup.

Comment: I just meant an `ObjectProperty<LocalTime>`. Set it when the user OKs the choice and you hide the popup. Then you can just observe it for changes.

Comment: I shall do that! Thank you. Why don't ya drop an official answer and I'll choose you. You have been helping me on JavaFX since the day I started several months ago, lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expose a `ReadOnlyProperty` representing the value. The user of your popup can then just observe the property.

Here's a proof of concept using a `DatePicker`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.PopupWindow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class DatePickerPopupExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label dateLabel = new Label(LocalDate.now().toString());
        Button changeButton = new Button("Change");

        HBox root = new HBox(5, dateLabel, changeButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        changeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            DatePickerPopup popup = new DatePickerPopup();
            popup.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldDate, newDate) -> {
                dateLabel.setText(newDate.toString());
            });
            Bounds buttonBds = changeButton.getBoundsInLocal();
            Point2D loc = changeButton.localToScreen(buttonBds.getMaxX(), buttonBds.getMinY());
            popup.showPopup(primaryStage, loc.getX(), loc.getY());
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class DatePickerPopup  {
        private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<LocalDate> value = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

        private final Popup popup ;

        public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<LocalDate> valueProperty() {
            return value.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public final LocalDate getValue() {
            return valueProperty().get();
        }
        public DatePickerPopup(LocalDate date) {

            value.set(date);

            DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(date);
            Button okButton = new Button("OK");
            okButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                popup.hide();
                value.set(picker.getValue());
            });
            Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
            cancelButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                popup.hide();
            });

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setCenter(picker);
            HBox buttons = new HBox(5, okButton, cancelButton);
            buttons.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.setBottom(buttons);

            popup = new Popup();
            popup.getContent().add(root);
        }

        public DatePickerPopup() {
            this(LocalDate.now());
        }

        public void showPopup(Stage owner, double x, double y) {
            popup.show(owner, x, y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```